# Program to generate fibonacci series in GNU Prolog is giving an instantiation error

Tags: prolog, fibonacci, instantiation-error

This is my code:-

```
fib(0,0).
fib(1,1).
fib(F,N) :-
    N>1,
    N1 is N-1,
    N2 is N-2,
    F is F1+F2,
    fib(F1,N1),
    fib(F2,N2),
    write(F," ,").
```

On consulting in GNU Prolog, I am getting:

```
| ?- consult('C:/GNU-Prolog/bin/fib.pl').
compiling C:/GNU-Prolog/bin/fib.pl for byte code...
C:/GNU-Prolog/bin/fib.pl compiled, 3 lines read - 1253 bytes written, 15 ms

yes
| ?- fib(F,2).
uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,(is)/2)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instantiation error is caused by the attempt to calculate `F` before the values of `F1` and `F2` have been determined. The simplest solution would to move `F is F1+F2` after the recursive calls such that your program becomes

```
fib(0,0).
fib(1,1).
fib(F,N) :- 
    N>1,
    N1 is N-1,
    N2 is N-2,
    fib(F1,N1),
    fib(F2,N2),
    F is F1+F2,
    write(F," ,").
```

(thanks to @mbratch for reminding) `write` has only one argument, i.e., `write(F," ,").` should be `write(F), write(" ,").`

You should be however careful with the output. The program above would print out the same value multiple times: e.g., to calculate `fib(F,3)` it will invoke `fib(F1,2)` and `fib(F2,1)` while `fib(F1,2)` will invoke `fib(F11,1)` and `fib(F12,1)` resulting in the following output `1, 1, 2, 1, 3`. Is this really what you need?

Comment: @Alexander You are right..it is displaying the same value multiple times. Is there any way in which I can display the complete series correctly?

Comment: @mbratch Thanks for the valuable information.Guess that was what was causing the error. 
And to add to the answer, the order of defining the argument matters as well. So the definition "N2 is N-2" should come just before "fib(F2,N2)". Having said that, is it possible to get the series in a single go in GNU Prolog?

Comment: @user3341381 what kind of output do you need?

Comment: ?-fib(F,5) for e.g. should return
F=11235 or even F=01123
or simply display the fibonacci series without assigning values to F like-
?-fib(F,5)
11235
@Alexander

Answer (score 2):

You probably need `F is F1+F2` after having instantiated `F1` and `F2`. The following is an exact adaptation of your code to something that works. Now, I'm sure it's exactly what you want (besides, it fails for large values of N, large being impressively small here).

```
fib(0,0).
fib(1,1).
fib(F,N) :-
    N>1,
    N1 is N-1,
    N2 is N-2,
    fib(F1,N1),
    fib(F2,N2),
    F is F1+F2,
    format('~w, ',[F]).
```

I used `format` instead of `write`, I'm not sure that `write/2` does what you expect.

Comment: Thanks. But i'm really confused. What does write/2 mean and how is format different from it?

Comment: @user3341381 in Prolog, when referring to a predicate, you give the name and the arity (number of accepted arguments). `write/2` means the `write` predicate with two arguments. `write/1` and `write/2` are simple write predicates with no control over format. `format/2` lets you control the format of what you're writing. See the online manual for details.

Comment: @mbratch I get it..Thanks! :) The online manual is hard to comprehend .

Answer (score 1):

```
fab1(1,1).
fab1(2,1).
fab1(N,T):-
    N>2,
    N1 is N-1,
    N2 is N-2,
    fab1(N1,T1),
    fab1(N2,T2),
    T is (T1+T2),
```

Answer (score 1):

domains

```
N,N1,N2,Ans=integer
```

predicates

```
test(integer,integer)
findfibo(integer,integer)
go
```

clauses

```
go:-
    write("Enter number"),nl,
    readint(N),
    test(1,N).
go.
test(0,N).
test(X,N):-
    X<=N,
    findfibo(X,Ans),
    write(Ans," ,"),
    X1=X+1,
    test(X1,N).



findfibo(1,1).
findfibo(2,1).
findfibo(N,Ans):-
    N>1,
    N1=N-1,
    N2=N1-1,
    findfibo(N1,Ans1),
    findfibo(N2,Ans2),
    Ans=Ans1+Ans2.
```

sample output
Goal: go
     Enter number
     10
     1 , 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 45, 55,Yes